# What's the Canadian equivalent of a Biennial Flight Review?

Tags: canada

Is there an equivalent? Googling I didn't learn much.

Comment: verve you have to put a better description of what you are asking like more than 2 sentences. I am not trying to be mean, but somebody noted me today saying I had to put a better description into my questions because they didn't make sense and I am having trouble understanding the question.

Comment: @Ethan I have no idea how else to ask it. Just that one question...as said in the title..☺

Comment: @Ethan What's the Canadian name for a BFR?

Comment: That makes sense and now I understand your question I will do a little research

Comment: Can't seem to find a answer for you I only found definitons of the word have you tried Yahoo and Bing search engines

Answer (score 3):

There is a requirement to [complete a flight review every two years](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/general-personnel-current-1810.htm). I guess it's technically just a 'FR' but for all intents and purposes it is a BFR!